# Content inside table row in react component not aligning with other row after applying overflow hidden with other css styling

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sass, html-table

In my react component, I have an html table with some css properties. Everything works well presently but the content of the first row is not aligning with other two rows of the table. It goes ahead of other row contents. I was applying overflow hidden and other properties. Here is the link to my codesandbox of what i have

[Codesandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-fog-nwu30?file=/src/styles.css)

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

    <table id="customers">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Company</th>
  <th>Contact</th>
  <th>Country</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>  <div>
  bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
  bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
  bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
  bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
  bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
  </div>
  </td>
  <td>Maria Anders</td>
  <td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
  <td>Christina Berglund</td>
  <td>Sweden</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
  <td>Francisco Chang</td>
  <td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ernst Handel</td>
  <td>Roland Mendel</td>
  <td>Austria</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Island Trading</td>
  <td>Helen Bennett</td>
  <td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Königlich Essen</td>
  <td>Philip Cramer</td>
  <td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
  <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
  <td>Canada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
  <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
  <td>Italy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>North/South</td>
  <td>Simon Crowther</td>
  <td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Paris spécialités</td>
  <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
  <td>France</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>




  </div>

  );
}
```

Style.css

```
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  /* height: 20px;
  overflow-y: hidden; */
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}

tbody tr td {
  max-width: 100px;
}
tbody tr td div {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-column-width: 150px;
    column-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Whats the desired result you want?

Comment: I want the text under Company to start on the same line as contact and country and still maintain the same height of the row with overflow hidden @Grumpy

Comment: why is this a question, look at the text you are using on the first td, use standard real world texts such as lorem ipsum, you dont even need overflow:hidden; , i checked it and there isn't any problem

Comment: I needed the text under Company to start on the same line as contact and country and still maintain the same height of the row with overflow hidden.

Comment: Set te td height t for example to 1em.